# :active doesn't work on PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, transition

I'm trying to have a `<div>` that when you touch it, it slowly changes its background color.

I'm using the `:active` pseudo class for that:

```
div {
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    -o-transition: all .7s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .7s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s linear; 
}

div:active {
    background: #E5CC00;
}
```

Works perfectly on Chrome, but doesn't work on PhoneGap/Android. I've also tried `:hover`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The :active pseudo class doesn't work on the div tag on Android. It does work on the anchor tag though. Check out this StackOverflow answer:

[How to simulate :active css pseudo class in android on non-link elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940429/how-to-simulate-active-css-pseudo-class-in-android-on-non-link-elements)