# Change background color of a link on touch

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch

I'm trying to change the background color of an  link when the user touches/taps on a mobile, although the following code works, sometimes the link remains black and doesn't change back to white when you release, is there a better way of coding it?

```
$('#test').bind('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});

$('#test').bind('touchend', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});​
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of jQuery file are you using?

Answer (score 11):

This can be done in CSS without jQuery:

```
a:active
{
    background-color: black;
}
```

### Note about compatibility with the Android's stock browser

For some reason, the code above does not work in the Android's stock browser *(and maybe some other browsers)*. However it will work once you add the `ontouchstart=""` argument to the `<body>` tag like so:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

Also, the Android stock browser highlights the links by default *(with blue background, on my phone)*. To disable this, type:

```
a
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13562494/1935077) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522742/1935077) for more details.

#### [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8zLpn/4/)